# Pandas: Cascading Partition over multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
nodename   ip               <otherfields>
amelia     192.168.23.8     <...>
boris      10.8.45.3        <...>
boris      192.168.67.4     <...>
clyde      192.168.45.3     <...>
darwin     192.168.67.4     <...>
ellen      192.168.23.9     <...>
```

And I want to partition it by grouping together all elements that have at least one of my keys (in this example, nodename and ip) in common, and then working with each 'clump in turn.

```
          nodename   ip               <otherfields>
      clump1:
          amelia     192.168.23.8     <...>
          ellen      192.168.23.8     <...>
      clump2:
          boris      10.8.45.3        <...>
          boris      192.168.67.4     <...>
          darwin     192.168.67.4     <...>
      clump3:
          clyde      192.168.45.9     <...>
```

Note how in clump2, although (boris, 10.8.45.3) shares no common values with (darwin, 192.168.67.4), they are linked together by their 'common neighbour' (boris, 192.168.67.4)

For broader context on this, my actual problem involves partitioning my DF using 4 distinct keys.  It takes several preceding steps to generate the DataFrame (which contains on the order of 10 000 rows), and will have several steps working with each 'clump' in turn.  At the moment, the data is handled in a massive and unwieldy Excel VBA macro that does multiple passes over the data, pulling out one 'clump' at a time.

Comment: I don't think there is a pure `pandas` way to do it. You'll have to discover connected components (by using disjoint-set, for example). To see the problem, consider the following dataset: `(a, 1.1.1.1), (b, 1.1.1.1), (b, 1.1.1.2), (c, 1.1.1.2), (c, 1.1.1.3), ...`. For such dataset, all the rows would be in the same clump.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

I ended up looping through my dataset using the following algorithm:

```
1. Select first unmatched row currently in the dataset and use that to initialise sets of search keys.

2. Iteratively select all rows matching the keys, and rebuild the sets of search keys.

3. When the sets of search keys stabilises, write a marker field so the records are not selected at step 1 of the algorithm.

4. Repeat from step 1.
```

A code snippet for step 2 is below.  It goes into an infinite loop if all sets of keys are empty, and it isn't as fast as a vectorised/map-reduce/multi-threaded solution has the potential be, but my computer can choke through a 20k dataset in ~15 minutes, which is "good enough" at this stage.

```
i = 0
while not (nodename_set == servername_set_2 and ip_set == ip_set_2):
    nodename_set = nodename_set_2
    ip_set = ip_set_2
    built = all.loc[all['nodename'].isin(nodename_set) | all['ip'].isin(ip_set)]
    #build the comparator keys
    #the lamba filter purges nans
    nodename_set_2 = set(filter(lambda v: v==v, built['nodename']))
    ip_set_2 = set(filter(lambda v: v==v, built['ip']))
    itcount = itcount + 1
else:
    all.loc[all['nodename'].isin(nodename_set) | all['ip'].isin(ip_set), 'groupID'] = i
    i = i+1 #i is the groupID counter
```